# best way to root cause the runtime error in C++

Tags: c++, runtime-error

My application (a grpc service) crashes sometimes for std::vector.reserve, I have scanned all the usage in our application code, I suspect this is from some library.

What is the suggested way to debug/root-cause where this issue is from? Is signal the right hook to print backtrace?

For reference, this is where I'm thinking - https://github.com/varchar-io/nebula/blob/master/src/service/server/NebulaServer.cpp#L428-L449

Thank you for your suggestions and ideas, thanks!

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::reserve
I0725 19:45:22.087189     1 NebulaServer.cpp:430] Exiting nebula server by signal: 6
```

Comment: Code and error do not line up (line 430 is an empty line). [std::vector::reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) needs a `std::size_t` perhaps it got a negative signed integer value as input somehow?

Comment: *My application (a grpc service) crashes* -- `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'` -- Given this, that isn't a crash.  That is a thrown C++ exception -- using a debugger would show exactly what code you wrote that caused the exception to be thrown.  A crash is when your program terminates for no apparent reason.

Comment: There are various ways that this could happen. You could have bad logic for sizing, a negative size value (as already suggested), bad data resulting from a myriad of possibilities such as memory stomping, dangling references/pointers or data races... But the function linked in the question is already at the "too late" point for debugging. You must locate the exception before it's caught. Focus first on finding a reliable way to reproduce. If attaching a debugger is for some reason not an option, add diagnostic logging to your application along with additional try-catch blocks to isolate it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments so far. 

The issue happened in production once in a while, it is no way to attach a debugger or predict when it happens. That's why I asked for a generic way to collect more clues.

what I have done is guard size before reserve call in all the suspicious places I can find. Something like this - https://github.com/varchar-io/nebula/blob/master/src/service/server/QueryHandler.cpp#L440-L441

Comment: If there is no better way, maybe I have to write a reserve wrapper (assuming the error is happened in my app code rather than deep somewhere in a lib) to proactive check the size

```
reserve(std::vector<T>& vector, size_t size, std:string call_site) {
  if(size > 0xffffff) {
    caught it!
  }
}
```

Comment: With this 3 lines of error message it will be hard to find the locating where the exception is thrown. I already did such an locating of code line if the exception address is known (for WEC2013 programs) -- using a map of function addresses and the possibility to (re-)generate the assembly output of the compiler. Of course, this is not necessarily the line of code that **caused** the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's way too narrow a definition for crash. Crash need not be mutually exclusive to a thrown exception, either. You describe as a crash, I call an unexpected crash. If a program fails to catch an exception and terminates, I would generally call a crash, and I feel like it's not a confusing term. It might be too generic, depending on who you're talking with, but it's totally valid.

Comment: @ShawnCao: If you have access to the machine, see if you can set up post-mortem debugging. This will create a dump file of your process when it crashes, which you can then debug, either with WinDebg or VisualStudio. If you're lucky you'll at least get a call stack of the moment the exception is thrown and the values of variables in the current scope.
See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging

Comment: Thanks @nick for the idea, will try! But my service is running on Linux, not sure if the ms tool works for it.

Comment: @ShawnCao: Best of luck ! And don't let WinDgb/ntsd drive you crazy, they are pretty much Windows stone-age tools ;)

Comment: @ShawnCao: Did you ever solve this ? I just came upon (Google Crashpad)[https://github.com/chromium/crashpad], and thought of this thread :)

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for remembering this thread. Yes, I solved it by mostly logging, seeing where it crashes and keeps narrowing down and coming up with a hypothesis, didn't take me too many iterations to fix it.

So I didn't end up with a dump analysis.